# How can I create and use new function in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, aggregates

How can I create new function and use this new function in my DataFrame, so as to add new column during aggregation ?
From my DataFrame I took "Wind direction" and "Temperature" and for these columns I want to aggregate it and create table with mean of "Wind direction" and difference between value for all cities and mean "aa", and the same for "Temperature". Nevertheless, in column where I use my function "aa" I have 0. Where is the problem, could you write me appropriate line of code ?

```
def aa(x):
    return x - np.mean(x)

file.groupby(["City"]).agg({"Wind direction":[np.mean, aa], "Temperature":["mean", aa]})
```

Comment: Your `aa` function is not an aggregation.

Comment: What youre needing is the pandas `.apply()` method. If you add a bit more code, as well as some text lines showing the data you're starting from in the df and the output you want, we can help you.

Comment: I would like to create method "aa" and use it in my .agg() method, this "aa" method should presents the equation result of "Temperature" in certain city minus mean temperaturę in all cities. I use this kind of columns: file.columns = ["Station_ID", "City", "Date", "Time", "Temperature", "Wind Speed",
                "Wind direction", "Humidity", "Total rainfall", "Pressure"]

Comment: Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58476401/edit) your question to add relevant informations. Is not totally clear to me what you want to achieve, but from what you describe, I am pretty sure that `agg` is not the correct method to use here. As said by @RightmireM, you should explain better what you want. Please, provide a sample input and a sample of desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying `aa` at the wrong group-by level. Here a quick example:

```
np.random.seed(1)
size = 10
file = pd.DataFrame({
    'City': np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_uppercase), size),
    'Wind direction': np.random.randint(0, 360, size),
    'Temperature': np.random.randint(1, 100, size)
}).sort_values('City').reset_index(drop=True)
```

`df`:

```
  City  Wind direction  Temperature
0    A             252           87
1    F             129           30
2    F             254           95
3    I             281           69
4    J             178           88
5    L              71           15
6    L             276           88
7    M             237           51
8    P             357           97
9    Q             156           14
```

Your original code...

```
def aa(x):
    return x - np.mean(x)

file.groupby(["City"]).agg({"Wind direction":[np.mean, aa], "Temperature":["mean", aa]})
```

.. produces:

```
     Wind direction                  Temperature               
               mean               aa        mean             aa
City                                                           
A             252.0                0        87.0              0
F             191.5    [-62.5, 62.5]        62.5  [-32.5, 32.5]
I             281.0                0        69.0              0
J             178.0                0        88.0              0
L             173.5  [-102.5, 102.5]        51.5  [-36.5, 36.5]
M             237.0                0        51.0              0
P             357.0                0        97.0              0
Q             156.0                0        14.0              0
```

Notice how only those cities that appear twice has values in the result table? When you have only 1 data point for the city, `x == np.mean(x)` so their difference is 0.

---

## Solution

Define your aggregate function as:

```
def aa(col):
    # Difference between the local (city) mean and the global (entire column) mean
    return col.mean() - file[col.name].mean()

file.groupby(["City"]).agg({"Wind direction":[np.mean, aa], "Temperature":["mean", aa]})
```

Result:

```
     Wind direction        Temperature      
               mean     aa        mean    aa
City                                        
A             252.0   32.9        87.0  23.6
F             191.5  -27.6        62.5  -0.9
I             281.0   61.9        69.0   5.6
J             178.0  -41.1        88.0  24.6
L             173.5  -45.6        51.5 -11.9
M             237.0   17.9        51.0 -12.4
P             357.0  137.9        97.0  33.6
Q             156.0  -63.1        14.0 -49.4
```

Comment: in your Solution in method "aa" there is line:                  return col.mean() - file[col.name].mean() and it presents the solution of mean of "col" minus mean of entire column "col", but each city has only one Temperature, so we do not need mean Temperature for each City, so will be correct to write: return col - file[col.name].mean() ?